# Como transformar um JSON com Jolt?

Tags: java, json

Eu tenho um *json* que contém categorias e subcategorias, gostaria de transforma-lá utilizando o jolt.

**Disso:**

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alimentos",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Arroz"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Azeites"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Beleza e Higiene",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Óleos essenciais"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Sabonetes"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Para isso:**

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alimentos",
        "parent_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Arroz",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Azeites",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Beleza e Higiene",
        "parent_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Óleos essenciais",
        "parent_id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Sabonetes",
        "parent_id": 4
    }
]
```

**Tentativa:**

```js
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "categories.@(1,id).category_id",
        "name": "categories.@(1,id).name",
        "children": {
          "*": {
            "id": "categories.@(1,id).category_id",
            "name": "categories.@(1,id).name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: O que é Jolt? Poderia colocar uma das suas tentativas na pergunta?

Comment: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt